# performItemClick not working after setAdapter

Tags: android, click

[SOLVED]

I have the following structure in my code:

```
ListView accountListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.accountListing);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_view_item, R.id.nameTextView, currentAccounts);
accountListView.setAdapter(adapter);

accountListView.performItemClick(null, 0, 0);
```

currentAccounts is an array, and it has data on it.

When I try to performItemClick after setting the adapter, I get a NullPointerException.

I also override the OnKeyPress, to run the "performItemClick" and it works fine.

I would like to know WHY it doesn't work when trying to perform the click after setting the adapter. (after some debugging I saw that the lastVisiblePosition is -1) WHY?

[EDIT]

Using `((ListView)findViewById(R.id.accountListing)).performItemClick(null, 0, 0);` works, EXCEPT, if used right after setting the adapter. (look at the comments for more info)

[EDIT 2]

Stack Trace:

```
07-24 13:07:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(9455): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-24 13:07:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(9455): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.device/com.app.device.WelcomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-24 13:07:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
07-24 13:07:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
07-24 13:07:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
07-24 13:07:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
07-24 13:07:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-24 13:07:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-24 13:07:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
07-24 13:07:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 13:07:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-24 13:07:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
07-24 13:07:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
07-24 13:07:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-24 13:07:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(9455): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-24 13:07:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at com.app.device.WelcomeActivity.unselectViews(WelcomeActivity.java:1637)
07-24 13:07:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at com.app.device.WelcomeActivity.access$24(WelcomeActivity.java:1632)
07-24 13:07:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at com.app.device.WelcomeActivity$27.onItemClick(WelcomeActivity.java:1447)
07-24 13:07:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
07-24 13:07:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1280)
07-24 13:07:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at com.app.device.WelcomeActivity.UpdateAccountList(WelcomeActivity.java:1653)
07-24 13:07:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at com.app.device.WelcomeActivity.onCreate(WelcomeActivity.java:238)
07-24 13:07:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5163)
07-24 13:07:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
07-24 13:07:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2061)
07-24 13:07:56.710: E/AndroidRuntime(9455):     ... 11 more
```

Thanks in advance!

[SOLUTION]

I was trying to performItemClick on the `onCreate()` method, but the screen is not fully visible to the user. Using `onWindowFocusChanged()` worked! [onWindowFocusChanged() on Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged%28boolean%29).

Thanks everybody.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#performItemClick(android.view.View, int, long). you are passing null as the first parameter

Comment: The performItemClick requires a View, and even if I use adapter.getView(0,null,null), it gives me the NULLPOINTER error. What should I use then?

Comment: you are not passing view as param you are passing 0. also check the other params to be passed

Comment: The real problem is that the code itself works,   `((ListView)findViewById(R.id.accountListing)).performItemClick(null, 0, 0);`, EXCEPT, if I use it after setting the adapter!

Comment: I've have this method for OnKeyDown 
`public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
 ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.accountListing)).performItemClick(null, 0, 0);
  return false;
};` and it works like a charm, but if I try to select a View right after setting the adapter, NULLPOINTER error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

I was trying to performItemClick on the `onCreate()` method, but the screen is not fully visible to the user. Using `onWindowFocusChanged()` worked! [onWindowFocusChanged() on Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged%28boolean%29).

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing null as parameter for the perfomItemClick, have you tried:

```
ListView accountListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.accountListing);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_view_item,         R.id.nameTextView, currentAccounts);
accountListView.setAdapter(adapter);
accountListView.performItemClick(adapter, 0, 0);
```

Hope this helps...

Regards!

Comment: The performItemClick requires a View, and even if I use `adapter.getView(0,null,null)`, it gives me the NULLPOINTER error.

[performItemClick (Android DOC)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#performItemClick)

[Adapter.getView (Android DOC)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to pass accountListView in parameter to performItemClick instead of null .

Comment: The performItemClick requires a View, and even if I use `adapter.getView(0,null,null)`, it gives me the NULLPOINTER error.

[performItemClick (Android DOC)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#performItemClick)

[Adapter.getView (Android DOC)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView)

Comment: And with this ?
accountListView.performItemClick(
    accountListView.getAdapter().getView(0, null, null), 0, 0);

Comment: Also, NULLPOINTER :/
Check [my comment in the first post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820446/performitemclick-not-working-after-setadapter/17821186?noredirect=1#comment26028364_17820446)